# Bootstrap 4 scrollSpy require any kind of jQuery code for a border-bottom active state?

Tags: jquery, css, bootstrap-4, scrollspy

I'm having a hard time implementing Bootstrap 4 scrollSpy on my site with an active state red border-bottom onScroll and/or onClick.

This is what I want whenever I scroll to a section or click on it:

[image: Active State Border Bottom]

Here's my [Codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/pppZYB)

**What is the Bootstrap/CSS only way to make a Border Bottom appear only in its active state on scrollSpy and/or onClick?**

I'm fairly new to bootstrap 4, and I'm still learning with jQuery and/or JS.
Please help me find a solution with bootstrap or css or at least a minimalist approach with few lines of jQuery to fix this problem. Thank you!

CSS:

```
    body {
  position: relative;
}

    .navbar-nav .nav-link {
    margin-right: 15px;
    margin-left: 15px;
}

.navbar-nav li a{color:#d3d3d3;}

.navbar-nav li a:hover {color:#333;}

.navbar-expand-sm .navbar-nav a:hover:before {
  border-bottom: 5px solid #fff; 
  bottom: -7px; width:auto;
  content: " ";
  left:18px;
  position: absolute;
  right:18px;
}

.navbar-expand-sm .navbar-nav .active a::after {
  border-bottom: 5px solid red;
  bottom: -7px; width:auto;
  content: " ";
  left:18px;
  position: absolute;
  right:18px;
}
.navbar-nav > li {
  float: left;
  position: relative;
}

.custom-toggler .navbar-toggler-icon {
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf8,%3Csvg viewBox='0 0 32 32' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'%3E%3Cpath stroke='rgba(255, 0, 0, 1)' stroke-width='2' stroke-linecap='round' stroke-miterlimit='10' d='M4 8h24M4 16h24M4 24h24'/%3E%3C/svg%3E");
}
```

HTML:

```
<body data-spy="scroll" data-target=".navbar" data-offset="50">
<div class="wrapper">
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm bg-dark navbar-dark fixed-top"> 
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">
<img src="/assets/brand/bootstrap-solid.svg" width="30" height="30" class="d-inline-block align-top" alt="">CMM
</a>

  <button class="navbar-toggler custom-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
  <ul class="navbar-nav ml-md-auto">
    <li class="nav-item active">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#section1">Section 1</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#section2">Section 2</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#section3">Section 3</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item dropdown">
      <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbardrop" data-toggle="dropdown">
        Section 4
      </a>
      <div class="dropdown-menu">
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#section41">Link 1</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#section42">Link 2</a>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
  </div>
</nav>

<div id="section1" class="container-fluid bg-success" style="padding-top:70px;padding-bottom:70px">
  <h1>Section 1</h1>

</div>
<div id="section2" class="container-fluid bg-warning" style="padding-top:70px;padding-bottom:70px">
  <h1>Section 2</h1>

</div>
<div id="section3" class="container-fluid bg-secondary" style="padding-top:70px;padding-bottom:70px">
  <h1>Section 3</h1>

</div>
<div id="section41" class="container-fluid bg-danger" style="padding-top:70px;padding-bottom:70px">
  <h1>Section 4 Submenu 1</h1>

</div>
<div id="section42" class="container-fluid bg-info" style="padding-top:70px;padding-bottom:70px">
  <h1>Section 4 Submenu 2</h1>

</div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: I think it's impossible to do this trough CSS only. You have to check scroll position in order to do this, and this is done via javascript

Comment: If CSS is not possible. How would you go about doing this in js? Can jQuery do the trick instead?

Comment: @Phiter this is already done by JS but Bootstrap provide some class to use it without having to handle anything with JS. You simply need to well setup all the necessary classes https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/scrollspy/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost good, you need to simply correct a selector as the `active` class is applied to `a` tag. So you need to change this :

```
.navbar-expand-sm .navbar-nav .active a::after
```

by this:

```
.navbar-expand-sm .navbar-nav  a.active::after
```

```css
body {
  position: relative;
}

.navbar-nav .nav-link {
  margin-right: 15px;
  margin-left: 15px;
}

.navbar-nav li a {
  color: #d3d3d3;
}

.navbar-nav li a:hover {
  color: #333;
}

.navbar-expand-sm .navbar-nav a:hover:before {
  border-bottom: 5px solid #fff;
  bottom: -7px;
  width: auto;
  content: " ";
  left: 18px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 18px;
}

.navbar-expand-sm .navbar-nav a.active::after {
  border-bottom: 5px solid red;
  bottom: -7px;
  width: auto;
  content: " ";
  left: 18px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 18px;
}

.navbar-nav>li {
  float: left;
  position: relative;
}

.custom-toggler .navbar-toggler-icon {
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf8,%3Csvg viewBox='0 0 32 32' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'%3E%3Cpath stroke='rgba(255, 0, 0, 1)' stroke-width='2' stroke-linecap='round' stroke-miterlimit='10' d='M4 8h24M4 16h24M4 24h24'/%3E%3C/svg%3E");
}
```

```html
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.6/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <style>
    body {
      position: relative;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body data-spy="scroll" data-target=".navbar" data-offset="50">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm bg-dark navbar-dark fixed-top">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">
        <img src="/assets/brand/bootstrap-solid.svg" width="30" height="30" class="d-inline-block align-top" alt="">CMM
      </a>

      <button class="navbar-toggler custom-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>

      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
        <ul class="navbar-nav ml-md-auto">
          <li class="nav-item active">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#section1">Section 1</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#section2">Section 2</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#section3">Section 3</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item dropdown">
            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbardrop" data-toggle="dropdown">
        Section 4
      </a>
            <div class="dropdown-menu">
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#section41">Link 1</a>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#section42">Link 2</a>
            </div>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>

    <div id="section1" class="container-fluid bg-success" style="padding-top:70px;padding-bottom:70px">
      <h1>Section 1</h1>
      <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
      <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
    </div>
    <div id="section2" class="container-fluid bg-warning" style="padding-top:70px;padding-bottom:70px">
      <h1>Section 2</h1>
      <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
      <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
    </div>
    <div id="section3" class="container-fluid bg-secondary" style="padding-top:70px;padding-bottom:70px">
      <h1>Section 3</h1>
      <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
      <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
    </div>
    <div id="section41" class="container-fluid bg-danger" style="padding-top:70px;padding-bottom:70px">
      <h1>Section 4 Submenu 1</h1>
      <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
      <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
    </div>
    <div id="section42" class="container-fluid bg-info" style="padding-top:70px;padding-bottom:70px">
      <h1>Section 4 Submenu 2</h1>
      <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
      <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thank you for such a great example! Much love! :)